# Debugging a C++ DLL loaded into Excel via LoadLibrary()

Tags: c++, excel, vba, debugging

I'm writing a C++-based DLL which exports a few functions, let's say in a simple case

```
__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall Test()
{
  return 123;
}
```

Then, I load this DLL into a running Excel process via VBA, and invoke its Test function:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare Function Test Lib "MyLibrary.dll" () As Long

Sub executeTest()
  LoadLibrary "Path\To\MyLibrary.dll"
  Dim result As Long: result = Test()
End Sub
```

This works fine. But I don't seem to be able to Debug the C++ part of it.

I've tried firing up Excel, and before executing any code (i.e. befoer the DLL is loaded into Excel), attaching Visual Studio to the running Excel process.
When I set a breakpoint, it's "white" - aka "This breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document". Makes sense as my DLL hasn't been laoded into Excel yet.

Then, I execute the VBA code, which will load up the DLL and invoke the Test function. But the debugger's status doesn't change, the breakpoint remains in this state; at no point does it seem to realize the library has been loaded / is able to debug it.

Am I doing anything wrong there? Is there a way to debug calls to my DLL in this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you add an actual reference to the DLL (via tools/references) in the VBE?

Comment: Seems to be the same issue when adding a reference via tools/references

Comment: I'm not familiar with C++, but is there a COM registration for the library? The entry point would have a specific GUID that you should be able to find in the registry under `HKCR/CLSID/{GUID}` - that key would have an `InprocServer32` subkey, with a `CodeBase` path pointing to the DLL location - is it there and pointing to the build path?

Comment: It is indeed an ATL COM project; I'm still a bit overwhelmed by COM registration - it cannot be registered on a machine level due to lack of admin rights (and indeed none of the GUIDs are under HKCR/CLSID). Could there be anything similar in terms of user-level registration in any other registry tree?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but with my own side project (a COM add-in for the VBE, written in C#), I have to run VS as administrator in order to get a build to correctly register. If you leave the VBE opened with an early-bound reference to the DLL, can you still successfully build the DLL? If so, you're somehow not loading the DLL from the build location - VS shouldn't be able to overwrite the DLL while it's in use.

Comment: hmm, odd indeed - I'm stumped at this point... good luck!

Comment: Ah, my mistake (deleted the previous comment). Built the DLL without changing code, so VS didn't try to recreate it in the first place. In short - rebuilding the DLL while its referenced in VBA does indeed not work as it is in use

Comment: FYI it's possible to register a COM DLL without admin right. Either write yourself the keys in `HKCU` instead of `HKCR` or override the registry root with `RegOverridePredefKey` before the registration.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to add a __debugbreak directive. If the dll is build in debug, it should open the Windows Just in Time debugger.

```
__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall Test()
{
  __debugbreak(); 
  return 123;
}
```

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/f408b4et.aspx